# Kendo model binding causes not to show placeholder

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui

For example a `NumericTextBoxFor` like bellow, does not show a placeholder. Instead, it shows a default value, in this case 0.

```
@(Html.Kendo().NumericTextBoxFor(m => m.item)
    .Placeholder("Item Counts")
    .Format("# Item(s)")
    .Min(0)
)
```

I also tried to use `.Value(null)` to show a placeholder, but it didn't take effect!

Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the default value for integer in C# is zero. So, when you do not assign a value to "item", it will be defaulted to zero. If you want it to be null, you need to define it as nullable integer (`int?`) in your model:

```
public int? item { get; set; }
```